# Can an Azure table be split on partition keys in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, azure-table-storage

I am aware that an Azure Table has a composite key that is made up of a RowKey and PartitionKey. I am also aware that you can pull and Azure Table into PowerBI. I am new to PowerBI, so I am not sure if I am using the right term, but what I would like to be able to do is break my Azure Table into multiple tables in PowerBI based on the PartitionKey. Is this something that is possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You could do this - but why?

Comment: I have relationships between data in different partitions. I want to be able to join on those relationships. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import all your Azure Table data as one PowerQuery table. Then right click on the table in the PowerQuery editor and select Reference. This will give you a new table that points to the Azure Table data, call it "Partition Key Link" or "Partition Key Bridge". Remove all the row data columns. Right click on the partition key column header and select "Remove Duplicates". You now have a table of distinct Partition Keys. The go to your PowerBI model view. Create a relationship between the link table and the data from your Azure Table. You can then link your other data to the link table in order to get to a model that will work well in PowerBI.

[image]